# MySQL subConsulta

Tags: mysql-workbench

Qué tal, 
Tengo una consulta la cuál funciona bien.

```
SELECT PAPA.idPAPA AS PAPA, HIJO.idHIJO AS HIJO, NIETO.idNIETO AS NIETO,
BISNIETO.idBISNIETO AS BISNIETO
FROM PAPA 
LEFT JOIN HIJO ON HIJO.PreH=PAPA.idPAPA 
LEFT JOIN NIETO ON NIETO.PreN=HIJO.idHIJO 
LEFT JOIN BISNIETO ON BISNIETO.PreB=NIETO.idNIETO 
ORDER BY idPAPA,idHIJO,idNIETO,idBISNIETO ASC;
```

Me retorna la siguiente tabla, cuando ya ingrese 2 PAPÁS diferentes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cuál sí es correcto, sin embargo, quiero agregar un WHERE idPAPA="A", para que solo me de la consulta del PAPA "A".

Así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo está consulta pero no corre.

```
SELECT idPAPA, idHIJO, idNIETO, idBISNIETO
FROM
(SELECT PAPA.idPAPA AS PAPA, HIJO.idHIJO AS HIJO,NIETO.idNIETO AS
NIETO,BISNIETO.idBISNIETO AS BISNIETO 
FROM PAPA 
LEFT JOIN HIJO ON HIJO.PreH=PAPA.idPAPA 
LEFT JOIN NIETO ON NIETO.PreN=HIJO.idHIJO 
LEFT JOIN BISNIETO ON BISNIETO.PreB=NIETO.idNIETO 
WHERE idPAPA="A"
) ORDER BY idPAPA,idHIJO,idNIETO,idBISNIETO ASC
;
```

Gracias.

Comment: a que te refieres con "no corre", te arroja error o no te trae data?

Comment: Me arroja esto,
Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias 0.000 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las tablas dentro de la consulta deben tener un nombre, prueba esto :

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT PAPA.idPAPA AS PAPA, HIJO.idHIJO AS HIJO,NIETO.idNIETO AS
NIETO,BISNIETO.idBISNIETO AS BISNIETO 
FROM PAPA 
LEFT JOIN HIJO ON HIJO.PreH=PAPA.idPAPA 
LEFT JOIN NIETO ON NIETO.PreN=HIJO.idHIJO 
LEFT JOIN BISNIETO ON BISNIETO.PreB=NIETO.idNIETO 
WHERE idPAPA="A"
ORDER BY PAPA.idPAPA,HIJO.idHIJO,NIETOidNIETO,BISNIETO.idBISNIETO ASC
) as a 
;
```

Comment: Mm me arrojo esto, Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.idPAPA' in 'field list' 0.000 sec

Comment: Lo he corregido espero funcione así, ya que ahorita no puedo hacer pruebas

Comment: Me da esto, la posición de mi WHERE si es correcta?
 Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'idPAPA' in 'order clause'

Comment: pruebalo sin la linea del order by que nombres de campos te salen en la consulta?

Comment: Daaammmmn ya jalo, vos sos un crack, thank's.

Comment: por si las dudas prueba con el order by dentro de la subconsulta, así como lo deje en  mi respuesta